# autohotkey partial window title match (without ahk class)

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to add partial window title matching to #IfWinActive.
For example to match any notepad window, regardless wether the title is "Untitled - Notepad" or "MyFile - Notepad"

This should be very simple. My attemtps:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Regex
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow

#IfWinActive *.Notepad
+n::b
#IfWinActive
```

second attempt matchmode 2 should match anywhere

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive Notepad
+n::b
#IfWinActive
```

A test with using the full title Untitled - Notepad confirms that the code +n::b does substute Shift-n for Shift-b

NOTE: ahk_class is not an option as the class is different on every machine for the target programme TeXnicCenter

Comment: Nino, Is this all you have in your script, or is there more. I am asking because your second example is spot-on and exactly the way I use it too. (personally, I like to add a comma between IfWinActive and Notepad, like this: IfWinActive, Notepad). I assume that you did put SetTitleMatchMode, 2 at the top of your script. If this line is being placed below the first Return, the line will not be read and implemented unless it is part of a script.

Comment: `*.Notepad` isn't a valid regular expression.  You mean `.*Notepad`, i.e., 0 or more characters followed by "Notepad".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Robert Ilbrink said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872838/autohotkey-partial-window-title-match-without-ahk-class#comment24340524_16872838), my second example actually works, and the problem was that I did not place SetTitleMatchMode at the very top of my script.

The default example script for `^!n` was in effect and interfered. Not exactly sure why it does that, but placing SetTitleMatchMode at the top solved my problem.